# Stop worksheet from jumping to top of page when firing Cells.Select property

Tags: excel, vba, module, properties

This is the default **ThisWorkbook** code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    FixWidthHeight
End Sub
```

And this is my **FixWidthHeight** module:

```
Sub FixWidthHeight()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Selection.Rows.AutoFit
    Application.Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow, True
End Sub
```

What I want my code to do and in this particular order:

1. **Cells.Select** - Selects all cells in the entire worksheet
2. **Selection.Columns.AutoFit** - Autofits all column width
3. **Selection.Rows.AutoFit** - Autofits all row height
4. **Application.Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow, True** - Scrolls the last updated row to the top of the worksheet

The problem I have with this code is that it will not fire the last property **Application.Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow, True** because the **Cells.Select** property prevents it from firing. I have tested the code and found **Cells.Select** to be the culprit. When **Cells.Select** property is fired, it automatically jumps to the **first row on the top of the worksheet** and not the **last active/updated row**. It's as if **Cells.Select** cancels out **Application.Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow, True** and that is not what I want. So I would like to know if someone can help me fix this code to obtain my desired results specified. Thank you

Comment: You don't need to `Select` to begin with. `Columns.AutoFit`, `Rows.AutoFit` perhaps

Comment: @BigBen That won't work because then it won't select the entire worksheet to do AutoFit on. I already tried that btw.

Comment: Perhaps `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit` then. Or `Cells.Columns.AutoFit`. Generally [avoid `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `AutoFit` on the `UsedRange.Columns` and `UsedRange.Rows` and [avoid `Select`ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to begin with.

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Columns.AutoFit
    .Rows.AutoFit
End With
```

Then the `ActiveCell` remains unchanged and `Application.Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow, True` will work as desired.